# Builder pattern with inheritance

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I want to represent an web service URL request as an object, and found that there are lots of common parameters that could be "bubbled up" in an inheritance hierarchy. A request could have lots of parameters, some mandatory and other optional, for which I believe Bloch's Builder pattern is a nice option, emulating named arguments with a fluent interface.

Specifically, I'm designing for the Google Maps web service API, that has as general web service request

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/service/output?{parameters}
```

`service` and `output` are mandatory arguments, and `sensor` a mandatory parameter. There is also an optional parameter `language`.

Each service has its set of mandatory and optional parameters.The Geocode service has two optional parameters, `bounds` and `region`. It also has mutually exclusive mandatory parameters, `address` or `location`, that specify the type of service (direct or reverse geocoding, respectively). I represent this mutual exclusion with new children classes.

I imagine the class hierarchy as such:

```
  .-----.
  | Url |
  '-----'
     ^
     |
.---------.
| Request |
'---------'
     ^
     |----------------------------+--------------...
.---------.                 .------------.
| Geocode |                 | Directions |
'---------'                 '------------'
     ^                            ^
     |------------+               .
 .--------.  .---------.          .
 | Direct |  | Reverse |          .
 '--------'  '---------'
```

Then, I would like to do something like the following:

```
String output = "xml";
boolean sensor = true;
String address = "Av. Paulista, São Paulo, Brasil";
Bounds bounds  = new Bounds(-20, -10, -25, -20); //Geographic rectangle
String region  = "br";
String lang    = "pt-BR";
Coord location = new Coord(-12,-22);

DirectGeocodeRequestUrl direct = 
    new DirectGeocodeRequestUrl.Builder(output, sensor, address)
                               .bounds(bounds)
                               .language(lang)
                               .build();

ReverseGeocodeRequestUrl reverse = 
    new ReverseGeocodeRequestUrl.Builder(output, sensor, location)
                                .language(lang)
                                .region(region)
                                .build();
```

How can I create a Builder that uses arguments and methods from the class and superclasses in which it is inserted?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm building my answer upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/9138629/946814, but considering this multi-level hierarchy.

What we need is to replicate the same hierarchy with the Builder inner classes. As we want method chaining, we need a `getThis()` method that returns the leaf object of the hierarchy. In order to pass its type upward the hierarchy, the parent classes have a generic `T`, and the leaf binds `T` to itself.

It assures type-safety and avoids any exception throwing due to uninitialized mandatory parameters or typos, plus the nice fluent interface. However, it's a very costy and complex design to represent such a simple structure as an URL. I hope it is useful to someone - I preferred string concatenation at the end.

RequestUrl:

```
public abstract class RequestUrl{
    public static abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>{
        protected String output;
        protected boolean sensor;
        //Optional parameters can have default values
        protected String lang = "en"; 

        public Builder(String output, boolean sensor){
            this.output = output;
            this.sensor = sensor;
        }

        public T lang(String lang){
            this.lang = lang;
            return getThis();
        }

        public abstract T getThis();
    }

    final private String output;
    final private boolean sensor;
    final private String lang;

    protected <T extends Builder<T>> RequestUrl(Builder<T> builder){
        this.output = builder.output;
        this.sensor = builder.sensor;
        this.lang = builder.lang;
    }

    // other logic...
}
```

GeocodeRequestUrl:

```
public abstract class GeocodeRequestUrl extends RequestUrl {
    public static abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>
        extends RequestUrl.Builder<Builder<T>>{

        protected Bounds bounds;
        protected String region = "us";

        public Builder(String output, boolean sensor){
            super( output, sensor );
        }

        public T bounds(Bounds bounds){
            this.bounds = bounds;
            return getThis();
        }

        public T region(String region){
            this.region = region;
            return getThis();
        }

        @Override
        public abstract T getThis();
    }

    final private Bounds bounds;
    final private String region;

    protected <T extends Builder<T>> GeocodeRequestUrl(Builder<T> builder){
        super (builder);
        this.bounds = builder.bounds;
        this.region = builder.region;
    }

    // other logic...
}
```

DirectGeocodeRequestUrl:

```
public class DirectGeocodeRequestUrl extends GeocodeRequestUrl {
    public static class Builder<Builder>
        extends GeocodeRequestUrl.Builder<Builder>{

        protected String address;

        public Builder(String output, boolean sensor, String address){
            super( output, sensor );
            this.address = address;
        }

        @Override
        public Builder getThis(){
            return this;
        }

        public DirectGeocodeRequestUrl build(){
            return new DirectGeocodeRequestUrl(this);
        }
    }

    final private String address;

    protected DirectGeocodeRequestUrl(Builder builder){
        super (builder);
        this.address = builder.address;
    }

    // other logic...
}
```

ReverseGeocodeRequestUrl:

```
public class ReverseGeocodeRequestUrl extends GeocodeRequestUrl {
    public static class Builder<Builder>
        extends GeocodeRequestUrl.Builder<Builder>{

        protected Coord location;

        public Builder(String output, boolean sensor, Coord location){
            super( output, sensor );
            this.location = location;
        }

        @Override
        public Builder getThis(){
            return this;
        }

        public ReverseGeocodeRequestUrl build(){
            return new ReverseGeocodeRequestUrl(this);
        }
    }

    final private Coord location;

    protected ReverseGeocodeRequestUrl(Builder builder){
        super (builder);
        this.location = builder.location;
    }

    // other logic...
}
```

Comment: The overridden implementation of `getThis()` in the concrete classes should not be abstract.

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks. Though in my own version of this code it appears as though it requires accessing the generic methods (e.g. bounds, region) from the top-most abstract class down the inheritance tree (I have 3 levels).

Comment: ```protected RequestUrl(Builder builder)``` method will always complain for `Raw use of parameterized class 'Builder'`

Comment: @Ghilteras you're correct, I've fixed the constructors of the intermediate abstract classes to also be parameterized by the builder type.