# Using lombok's @Builder with inheritance and Jackson

Tags: java, design-patterns, jackson, lombok, builder-pattern

I am trying to use lombok's @Builder with inheritance and Jackson.

I was building things from https://reinhard.codes/2015/09/16/lomboks-builder-annotation-and-inheritance/, https://gist.github.com/pcarrier/14d3a8e249d804cfbdee and [Builder pattern with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941464/builder-pattern-with-inheritance)

Here is what i have

**UserInput.java**

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = UserInput.UserInputBuilder.class)
@Builder
@Data
public class UserInput {
    private int userId;
    private UsersChoice usersChoice;
    private ChoiceAttributes choiceAttributes;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class UserInputBuilder {

    }

    public enum UserChoice {
          CHOICE1,
          CHOICE2
    }
}
```

Based on user choice, corresponding ChoiceAttributes builder should be used.

**ChoiceAttributes.java**

```
public abstract class ChoiceAttributes {
    //nothing to do here
    public static class ChoiceAttributesBuilder {
    }

    public static ChoiceAttributesBuilder getMeMyBuilderBasedOnUserChoice(UserChoice userChoice)
    {
       ChoiceAttributesBuilder choiceAttributesBuilder = null;
       switch(userChoice){
            case CHOICE1:
                choiceAttributesBuilder = new ChoiceAttributesForChoice1.ChoiceAttributesForChoice1Builder(); //err!! stuck?
       }
}
```

**ChoiceAttributesForChoice1.java**

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ChoiceAttributesForChoice1.ChoiceAttributesForChoice1Builder.class)
@Builder
@Data
public class ChoiceAttributesForChoice1 extends ChoiceAttributes {
    private int x;
    //and so on

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class ChoiceAttributesForChoice1Builder extends ChoiceAttributesBuilder {
    }
}
```

**ChoiceAttributesForChoice2.java**

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ChoiceAttributesForChoice2.ChoiceAttributesForChoice2Builder.class)
@Builder
@Data
public class ChoiceAttributesForChoice2 extends ChoiceAttributes {
    private float y;
    //and so on

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class ChoiceAttributesForChoice2Builder extends ChoiceAttributesBuilder {
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? How can i build "UserInput" using its builder and ChoiceAttributes based on UsersChoice?