# Is there any way to define a generic method in a super class to reference the inheriting class's type?

Tags: java, generics

When defining something like this method:

```
class State {
   public void addOperator(Operator<? extends State> op) {
   }
}
```

Is there any way to define it in this way:

```
class State {
  public void addOperator(Operator<? extends this.getClass()> op) {
  }
}
```

So that any class inherting from **State** forces all passed in value to conform to its class-type.

I know that the above wont work, but is there anyway to force a generic wild-card to at least match the current classes type?

Comment: What was wrong with `Operator<? extends State> op` inside `State`?

Comment: No, self-types are not supported in Java.

Comment: It's not about it being wrong, it's about narrowing the types of objects that are accepted by the method at compile time. Elsewise I have to employ internal if-checks to verify that the passed value really conforms to what i was expecting.

Comment: Ok thank you, might as well make an answer so I can checkmark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already accepted an answer that claims your desired constraint can't be expressed in Java. If I understand the requirements correctly, the following solution comes close.

```
// You didn't flesh out what an operator does or provides,
// so I'll just make something up.
interface Operator<T> {
  void apply(T arg);
}

// Request that a derived type provide its own type as a type
// parameter, per the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP).
abstract class State<T extends State> {
  public void addOperator(Operator<? extends T> op) {
    final PrintStream s = System.out;
    s.print("Received an operator of concrete type ");
    s.print(op.getClass().getName());
    s.println('.');
  }
}

final class DerivedState extends State<DerivedState> {
}

public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DerivedState ds = new DerivedState();
    ds.addOperator(new Operator<DerivedState>() {
      // ...
    });

    // And the following will not compile:
    ds.addOperator(new Operator<Integer>() { /* ... */ });
  }
}
```

Note that `DerivedType`'s `apply()` method will only accept an `Operator` argument whose type parameter is `DerivedType`—or some type derived from `DerivedType`, but since `DerivedType` is final, no other such types exist.

What we *can't* do—which may be what Chris was alluding to—is mandate that the type parameter provided to `State` is in fact the derived type itself. We can't prevent the following definition, where one class supplies another as the type parameter for `State`:

```
final class AnotherDerivedState extends State<DerivedState> {
}
```

Here, one could call `AnotherDerivedState#addOperator()` with an `Operator<DerivedState>`, which is obviously *not* of type `Operator<AnotherDerivedState>`.

You can't prevent someone from deriving from `State` "incorrectly", but if you assume that people will follow the intended derivation pattern, you can help them use the rest of your library safely.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, didn't know about the CRTP. Kind of sad to see javas type system not being able to express this.

Comment: You're welcome. Here's another answer of mine from a few years ago where I also applied the CRTP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9138629/31818.

Answer (score -1):

A subclass can be used instead of the superclass at any time because of the inclusion polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks, so it's not possible

Answer (score -2):

Try writing

```
State.class
```

to get the Class object of State.

```
class State {
  public void addOperator(Operator<? extends State.class> op) {
  }
}
```

Although I am not sure that Class object inherit among them, they use generics, `Class<T>`.

So let's say we have `class Base`, and `class Derived extends Base`.
`Class<Derived>` probably does extends `Class<Base>`.

Instead, this scenario looks more promising

```
class State {
  public void addOperator(Operator<Class<? extends State>> op) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't compile and doesn't fix my problem