# is it possible for a parameterized class to extend itself in java?

Tags: java, generics

I came across this definition of a class that was written by someone else:

```
BaseClass<E extends BaseClass<E>>
```

All of the class's methods are then defined this way:

```
public<E> E setX(...) {
   // do stuff
   return this;
}
```

And an object of class BaseClass is used like this:

```
base.setX(..).setY(..).setZ()..
```

And it got me wondering as to how it works,why does it even compile,why it's used this way and if it's good practice to declare a class to extend itself.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "All of the class's methods are then defined this way:

public<E> E setX(...) {
   // do stuff
   return this;
} " I don't think that would compile as a method of `BaseClass`. First, the way you wrote it, `E` is generic on the method, unrelated to the class's `E`, and can be anything, so there is no way to guarantee that `BaseClass<E1>` is a subtype of `E2`. Even if you remove the `<E>` from the method so it uses the class's `E`, it is still not guaranteed that `BaseClass<E>` is a subtype of `E`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "extends" here is used to specify a boundary on the parametrization (E) and not for self-inheritance. Self inheritance in Java is prohibited, period.

Essentially it says:

`BaseClass` is parameterized with E. But E can not be of any type (like String, Integer, etc.) Instead E must be of type of something that extends BaseClass.

I saw this technique to create builders hierarchy which also look to be your case as well.

You might be interested in reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138027/builder-pattern-for-polymorphic-object-hierarchy-possible-with-java)

Comment: But shouldn't it be BaseClass<T<E> extends BaseClass<E>>? and then T can be a derived class of BaseClass<E>

Comment: T as a Parameterized Parameter? :) Ugh - I believe it won't compile...