# Method Chaining: How to use getThis() trick in case of multi level inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, method-chaining

My question is in context of [Method chaining + inheritance don’t play well together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069528/method-chaining-inheritance-dont-play-well-together-java).
But unfortunately all examples/answers of method chaining uses single level of inheritance.
My usecase involves multi level of inheritance for e.g

```
abstract class PetBuilder{...}
class  DogBuilder extends PetBuilder{..}
class DogType1Builder extends DogBuilder {...}
```

To construct a Dog Object,i will be using either DogBuilder or DogType1Builder

how to use getThis trick for the above use case?

I want to use **builder pattern for constructing a complicated Dog object(Dog Object Model)"**.
DogType1 will have some added properties.

so to use getThis Trick declaration of above classes will become like

```
abstract class PetBuilder<T extends PetBuilder<T>>
class DogBuilder<T extends DogBuilder<T>> extends PetBuilder<DogBuilder<T>>
class DogType1Builder extends DogBuilder<DogType1Builder>
```

Now this creates two problems

1.builder method in 'DogBuilder' will look like

```
public T someMethodInDog(String dogName) {
..
return (T)this; ///i dont want type casting and i cant use getThis Trick Here (compiler reports error for conversion from DogBuilder to T)
}
```

2.As DogBuilder has become parameterised,so to create instance of "DogBuilder" i will have to use

```
DogBuilder<DogBuilder> builder=new DogBuilder(); //passing <DogBuilder> type ...real pain
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? I don't see any reason why the same trick shouldn't work with multiple levels of inheritance. If you have a specific problem, please clarify and - preferably - give a concrete code example.

Comment: i have edited my question to clarify the problem

Answer (score 8):

The root of your problem is a class design issue: **you are trying to inherit from a concrete class**, which is almost always a mistake, and (your case in point) is bound to cause numerous problems. To stick with the example given in the referred thread, you should not be instantiating `Dog`, as in such a universe there can exist no `Dog`s in general, any more than `Pet`s - only `Poodle`s, `NewFoundland`s, `Spaniel`s etc. Consequently, `getThis` should not be implemented in mid-level (abstract) classes, only in the (concrete) leaf classes. And in all mid-level abstract classes, you should only refer to the generic type parameter `T`, instead of the actual class name.

Here is the example in [the answer to the referred thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070556/265143) rewritten according to the above rules:

```
public class TestClass {

  static abstract class Pet <T extends Pet<T>> {
    private String name;

    protected abstract T getThis();

    public T setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return getThis(); }
  }

  static class Cat extends Pet<Cat> {
    @Override protected Cat getThis() { return this; }

    public Cat catchMice() {
      System.out.println("I caught a mouse!");
      return getThis();
    }
  }

  // Dog is abstract - only concrete dog breeds can be instantiated
  static abstract class Dog<T extends Dog<T>> extends Pet<T> {
    // getThis is not implemented here - only in concrete subclasses

    // Return the concrete dog breed, not Dog in general
    public T catchFrisbee() {
      System.out.println("I caught a frisbee!");
      return getThis();
    }
  }

  static class Poodle extends Dog<Poodle> {
    @Override protected Poodle getThis() { return this; }

    public Poodle sleep() {
      System.out.println("I am sleeping!");
      return getThis();
    }
  }

  static class NewFoundland extends Dog<NewFoundland> {
    @Override protected NewFoundland getThis() { return this; }

    public NewFoundland swim() {
      System.out.println("I am swimming!");
      return getThis();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat c = new Cat();
    c.setName("Morris").catchMice();
    Poodle d = new Poodle();
    d.setName("Snoopy").catchFrisbee().sleep();
    NewFoundland f = new NewFoundland();
    f.setName("Snoopy").swim().catchFrisbee();
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually all my classes act as builder constructing a complicated object(Pet Object Model). so some builder properties of that object  are exposed via DogBuilder  and i want to reuse that in DogType1Builder (which itself has some more builder properties) which is a fair requirement. and since My Pet Object Model has a complicated object graph ,so i want to use a builder pattern for constructing it.

Comment: @harrybvp, I believe what I described above can be applied to a builder hierarchy too, as long as the corresponding class hierarchy obeys the same rules. I.e. if you do not want to construct generic `Dog` objects, only instances of concrete dog breeds, `DogBuilder` can be kept abstract too.

Comment: Unfortunately i want to construct 'DogBuilder' as well.

Comment: is there some way where `ZombiePoodle extends Poodle` and this work: `ZombiePoodle zp = new ZombiePoodle().sleep();` without overriding `sleep()` ? So, a concrete extending another.

Comment: I found it: `Poodle<P extends Poodle<P>> extends Dog<P>`, `ZombiePoodle extends Poodle<ZombiePoodle>`

Comment: @AquariusPower: Great, but now how does one `new Poodle()` now ? Cannot do `new Poodle<Poodle>()`.

Comment: @bertie I just did `Poodle p = new Poodle();` and it worked, here the code, but will be a bit hard to read: `public class TestPoodle {
 static class Poodle <P extends Poodle>{public void tstSleep(){};}
 static class ZombiePoodle <P extends ZombiePoodle> extends Poodle<P>{}
 static class UltraZombiePoodle <P extends UltraZombiePoodle> extends ZombiePoodle<P>{}
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Poodle p = new Poodle();
  p.tstSleep();
  UltraZombiePoodle uzp = new UltraZombiePoodle();
  uzp.tstSleep();
 }
}
`

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can use the `getThis` trick for multiple levels of inheritance. You have the super class, `Pet<T extends Pet<T>>`, the first subclass, `Dog extends Pet<Dog>`, and the second subclass `Poodle extends Dog`. With the `getThis` trick, you have the method `protected T getThis()` and methods like `public T rollOver()`. This means that both `Poodle` and `Dog` have the methods `protected Dog getThis()` and `public Dog rollOver()`.

I would follow [Michael Myers' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069586/758280) to use covariant return types.