# Java Multilevel Generic Inheritance

Tags: java, generics, multiple-inheritance, restful-architecture

The closest question I found ([Method Chaining: How to use getThis() trick in case of multi level inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655335/method-chaining-how-to-use-getthis-trick-in-case-of-multi-level-inheritance)) did not have a direct answer to my problem. I'm currently using morphia and am setting up a rest service. I've seen many versions of how to implement this and decided to do it this way. I am completely open to suggestions however, learning how to get through this problem, will help my coding practices, at least I think it will. Also, I know my naming conventions may be off so a correction in that I am open to as well :)

Here's my code:

```
                          1st
/*****************************************************************************/
public interface BaseRepository <T extends BaseEntity> {
    /* Methods Here */
}
public class BaseController<T extends BaseEntity> implements BaseRepository<T> {
    public BaseController(Class<T> type) {
         this.type = type;
    }
    /* Overridden Methods Here*/
}
                         2nd
/*****************************************************************************/
public interface UserRepository<T extends UserEntity> extends BaseRepository<UserEntity> {

    /* Methods Here */

}

public class UserController<T extends UserEntity> extends BaseController<UserEntity> implements UserRepository<T> {

    Class<T> type;

    public UserController(Class<T> type) {
        super(type); // <---- Error Here
        this.type = type;
    }
```

Eventually, I will want to have a StudentController, StaffController, etc. inherit from UserController. And BaseController will be the parent to other Controllers (not users). However, I did not know the proper way to go about this. I did try to satisfy

```
public UserController(Class<T> type) {
        super(type); // <---- Error Here
        this.type = type;
    }
```

replacing "type" in super(type) with UserEntity.class, however that would only allow the Basecontroller to return UserEntity properties. Any solutions? If there is a way...Like I said, I'm still learning and am completely open to other suggestions in approaching this issue or any advice in this particular problem. Much appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you intended was

```
public class UserController<T extends UserEntity> extends BaseController<T> 
                                                  implements UserRepository<T> {
```

as this would allow you to pass a `Class<T>` to the super class.

Comment: i don't know why i didn't do this first.... 1 character.

Comment: @MichaelVillar because generics and their error messages take a bit of getting use to. The first couple of years, I was often confused by them but that was a while ago now. ;)

Comment: yea I'm still fairly new with it, I appreciate the help! Thanks!