# How to reuse common extended Interface method in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, fluent-interface

I have these three Interfaces as part of the Fluent Interface API (where a lot of method chaining happens):

```
    interface VerifierA extends VerifierC {

      VerifierA method1();
      // other methods elided
    }

    interface VerifierB extends VerifierC {
     VerifierB method1();
       // other methods elided
    }

   interface VerifierC {
   VerifierA commonMethod();
   }
```

By declaring `commonMethod()` as `VerifierA` I can then chain methods 
`commonMethod().method1()` but not `commonMethod().method2()`;

How can I have `commonMethod()` in `VerifierC` return to both `VerifierA` or VerifierB as needed?

Comment: I think this is already asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069528/method-chaining-inheritance-don-t-play-well-together or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655335/method-chaining-how-to-use-getthis-trick-in-case-of-multi-level-inheritance

Comment: Having read through the referenced answer, I'm afraid I'm unable to apply it to my situation consisting of only interfaces...

Comment: Why you not simply let commonMethod return VerifierC and override in VerifierB to return VerifierB and VerifierA to return VerifierA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could solve it with generics:

```
interface VerifierA extends VerifierC<VerifierA> {
     VerifierC<VerifierA> method1();
}

interface VerifierB extends VerifierC<VerifierB> {
    VerifierC<VerifierB> method1();
}

interface VerifierC<T> {    
    T commonMethod();
}
```

Comment: +1 I was going to answer the same. Shouldn't the return type of VerifierB#method1 be `VerifierC<VerifierB>`?

Comment: Should in interface `VerifierB` the `method1()` have `<VerifierB>` then?

Comment: @Daij-Djan. Thanks. Works. Could you please suggest on the keywords to google to learn more? (apart from general "Java generics")

Comment: Assuming that both `VerifyA` and `VerifyB` have the same method (`method1`) intentionally, is there really a need for these interfaces? `VerifierC` can contain `method1` as well.

Comment: yes, because of chaining .. method1 needs to return A or B depending in which context it is