# Java inherited return type

Tags: java, inheritance, return-type

I've got a question about return types in inherited methods in Java. I've got a class and an inherited class. In the inherited class, there's a specific method. It also inherits a method from the parent class that returns instance of itself.

I want something like this class hierarchy:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo bar()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class FooInherited extends Foo {
    public Whatever baz()
    {
        return new Whatever();
    }
}
```

My question is if I can call the inherited method from its instance and then call the specific method without overriding the method to return the inherited class or casting the classes explicitly.

Now I want to have a code fragment like this :

```
FooInherited foo = new FooInherited();
Whatever w = foo.bar().baz();
```

I feel a difficulty in this, but I'm not very sure if Java has any time saving mechanism for programmers in such situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you override the method in the subclass you will have to cast:

```
FooInherited foo = new FooInherited();
Whatever w = ((FooInherited)foo.bar()).baz();
```

However, due to [covariant return types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) in java you can override it like this:

```
public class FooInherited extends Foo {


        @Override
        public FooInherited bar()
        {
            return this;
        }
 ...
 }
```

**After overriding** you no longer have to cast because the static type of foo is `FooInherited`:

```
FooInherited foo = new FooInherited();
Whatever w = foo.bar().baz();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use generics, but it gets ugly quickly.

```
class Base<This extends Base<This>> {

    public This myself() {
        return (This) this;
    }

}

class Sub<This extends Sub<This>> extends Base<This> {

    public void subOnly() {}

}

{
    Sub<?> sub = new Sub<>();
    sub.myself().subOnly();
    Base<?> base = sub;
    // base.myself().subOnly(); // compile error
}
```

The alternative is to override the method explicitly:

```
class Base {

    public Base myself() {
        return this;
    }

}

class Sub extends Base {

    @Override
    public Sub myself() {
        return this; // or return (Sub) super.myself();
    }

    public void subOnly() {}

}

{
    Sub sub = new Sub();
    sub.myself().subOnly();
    Base base = sub;
    // base.myself().subOnly(); // compile error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I thought, it's not possible then.

Comment: I had to implement the super declaration a bit different `Base <This extends Base<This>>` as pointed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1070556/1422630)

Comment: Correct, I forgot to add that inner generic argument

Comment: If the last class in the chain uses itself as type... when using the class no generic type needs to be specified: class SubSub extends Sub<SubSub> .... SubSub subSub = new SubSub();
  subSub.myself().subOnly().subSubOnly();

Answer (score 1):

`foo.bar()` returns a `Foo` instance and it has no method named as `baz()`,
so it is not possible to compile this statement: `Whatever w = foo.bar().baz();`