# What is the correct implementation of chainable getters/setters that use inheritance? (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance, chaining

I want to write a class in Java that is a parent class to abstract things out of the child class.

I want to be able to use this code, but I'm not sure if it's not possible with Java.

```
Frodo frodo = new Frodo();
child.addGold(10).goToMordor();
```

But isn't this code unsafe?

```
public class Bilbo
{
    private int gold;

    public Parent()
    {
        // Does something awesome
    }

    public Bilbo addGold(int amount)
    {
        this.gold += gold;
        return this;
    }

    public int getGold()
    {
        return this.gold;
    }
}

// Child class:
public class Frodo extends Bilbo
{
    // Does cool stuff
    public void goToMordor()
    {
        System.out.println("Traveling to Mordor...");
    }
}
```

Comment: That code will not work unless `Parent` has a print `method` too...

Comment: @delnan I just filled the code, but won't there by some typechecking errors?

Comment: @RyanDawkins No.  There won't be type checking errors. Here, child is a parent, so it can return itself in `setName` with no errors.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison As explained by Stefano above, the error comes from the fact that `Parent` has no `print`, coupled with the result of `setName` being a `Parent`.

Comment: @delnan That's not what OP asked.  OP said he filled in required code, asked if there'd be type-checking errors.  The answer is no. As long as `print` is defined in parent when he filled things out, there'll be no errors.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison The code *was* filled out an hour ago. The current code in the question is what OP considers filled out.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is possible in Java, and is safe.  It may seem a little odd to you in implementation though.  Consider:

```
public class Parent{
    private String name;

    public Parent setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName(){ return this.name;}

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Say my name!");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public void doChildStuff(){
        //child stuff.
    }

    @Override
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this.getName());
    }
}

Child child = new Child();
//this works as Parent defines print, and setName returns a Parent object.
child.setName("Bill gates").print();

//Compile error, as setName returns Parent, and Parent does not define 'doChildStuff.`
child.setName("Bill Gates").doChildStuff();
```

Your approach is fine, just be aware chaining calls won't work with any subclass of `Parent` which adds new methods.

Comment: Is it possible to have a generic based off of the class that is extending the child class if the parent class is abstract?

Comment: If I understand you, sure, you can do this.  That's what the question you were linked to yesterday suggests.  [Here it is again.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069528/method-chaining-inheritance-dont-play-well-together-java)