# Overriding a chained method

Tags: java

Let's have class `A` with a method useful for chaining:

```
class A {
  A foo() {
    // do stuff
    return this;
  }
}
```

You could now do `a.foo().foo().foo()` (think: builder pattern). Let class B extend it:

```
class B extends A {
}

B b;
```

Now invoking `b.foo()` returns actual type `B`, but declared `A`. Therefore I cannot write:

```
B other = b.foo();
```

I would have to write either:

```
B other = (B) b.foo();
```

Or override `foo()` in B:

```
class B extends A {
  @Override
  B foo() {
    super.foo();
    return this;
  }
}
```

Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: I'd have said that the overwrite is the nicest *possible* way to do this in Java.  But obviously, "niceness" is a subjective criterion.

Comment: I would suggest you can see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1070556/2274724

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method chaining + inheritance don’t play well together? (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069528/method-chaining-inheritance-don-t-play-well-together-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did this by implementing an additional generic method `as(type)` to the superclass. This helps to have a nicer cast for fluent interfaces.

```
class A {
    public A foo() {
        return this;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends A> T as(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (T) this;
    }
}

class B extends A  {}
```

So you can write `a.foo().as(B.class).methodOfB(..)`. And you do not need to reimplement foo() in all subclasses.

Comment: This is somewhat dirty... But still, interesting way of doing it.

Comment: You may declare the cast method like `public <T extends A> T $() { return (T) this;}` and then you can do it really dirty `a.foo().<B>$().methodOfB()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no you already listed the *nicest* way:

```
B other = (B) b.foo();
```

That would be the solution for *any* developer, who uses classes `A` and `B`.

Overwriting is for *you*, so that other developers could simply write `B other = b.foo();`

But there is actually no other way for the compiler to know, that

- `B` is *sort of* an `A`
- `B` is compatible, so that you won't use any information when instantiating an `A` but putting it in a `B`

The last one is the reason why you have to cast explicitly. Example:

```
 int myInt = 2;
 short myShort = (short) myInt; // correct
```

although this works, the compiler needs you to be explicit, because in many cases (when `myInt` is big) you will loose precision / information when casting to `short`.

If this one would work:

```
short myShort = myInt;   // wrong
```

Then the compiler would make an assumption on its own. But only the developer can know, if `myInt` will ever have a value that is bigger than a `short` can hold.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `class A` to have a generic type parameter of its implementing class and `foo()` could return this dynamic type:

```
class A<T extends A<T>> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T foo() {
        // do stuff
        return (T) this;
    }
}

class B extends A<B> {
    B bar() {
        // do other stuff
        return this;
    }
}
```

After this, the following is valid:

```
B b = new B();
b.foo().bar();
```

Comment: This is the "nicest" way. The jdk Enum type does this declaration and thanks to you I finally understood why.

Comment: Maybe you should declare B as `class B<T extends A<T>> extends A<T>`, too. Then you can go down the hierarchy with more subclasses of B.

Comment: @Cfx You can't do that. If you pass `T` to `A` like `A<T>`, `foo().bar()` -> `bar()` method is unknown on type `A` because type parameter was not `B` but `T` which extends `A<T>`. Try it. `bar()` is declared in class `B`, so that has to be passed to `A` if we want `bar()` to call on the return value of `foo()`.

Comment: Well, I meant to declare B like `class B<T extends B<T>> extends A<T>` and C like `class C extends B<C>` (more classes inbetween possible). The drawback is (and in that you are right) you can not get an instance of B by calling `b.foo()`. But you can have a C `new C().foo().bar().methodOfC()` (Because C is a B). So you can only widen the scope to the deepest class, not limit it back to B.

Answer (score 0):

I think the nice way to do this is to keep the reference as type `A`, since this is the least specific class that has the functionality that you require:

```
A other = b.foo();
```

You should only cast to type B if B contains some required functionality:

```
B another = (B)A;
another.somethingElse();
```

This is the same logic that makes:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

more desirable than:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```