# Why does casting to a generic subtype produce a warning?

Tags: java

I'm trying to subclass a Builder class, as described in [Subclassing a Java Builder class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164375/subclassing-a-java-builder-class).

The solution given there is pretty simple. Here is the base class:

```
public class NutritionFacts {

    private final int calories;

    public static class Builder<T extends Builder> {

        private int calories = 0;

        public Builder() {}

        public T calories(int val) {
            calories = val;
            return (T) this;
        }

        public NutritionFacts build() { return new NutritionFacts(this); }
    }

    protected NutritionFacts(Builder builder) {
        calories = builder.calories;
    }
}
```

And the subclass:

```
public class GMOFacts extends NutritionFacts {

    private final boolean hasGMO;

    public static class Builder extends NutritionFacts.Builder<Builder> {

        private boolean hasGMO = false;

        public Builder() {}

        public Builder GMO(boolean val) {
            hasGMO = val;
            return this;
        }

        public GMOFacts build() { return new GMOFacts(this); }
    }

    protected GMOFacts(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        hasGMO = builder.hasGMO;
    }
}
```

However, the `return (T) this;` in `NutritionFacts.Builder#calories(int)` results in a

> NutritionFacts.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

warning.

Given the generics, why is this cast unsafe? I know that `T extends Builder` and that `this` *is* a `Builder`, so why is the cast from `this` (`Builder`) to `T` (`extends Builder`) unsafe? The cast should never fail, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can very well fail. In

```
public T calories(int val) {
    calories = val;
    return (T) this;
}
```

you assume that `T` in

```
public static class Builder<T extends Builder> {
```

will always be bound to the type of the subclass. For example

```
public static class Real extends Builder<Real>{}
```

There is no way in Java to enforce that the type argument is the same as the declared type itself. Someone could very well have

```
public static class Fake extends Builder<Real> {}
```

in which case

```
Builder<Real> fake = new Fake();
Real real = fake.calories(4);
```

would fail with a `ClassCastException`.

If you know this will never happen, just ignore the warning. A cast is an explicit assertion that you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you: this was the pivotal sentence: "There is no way in Java to enforce that the type argument is the same as the declared type itself.", and then of course the examples made it clear.

Comment: Any way to remediate this situation design-wise?

Comment: @dimadima That's a good question. And it seems you found your current solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164375/subclassing-a-java-builder-class). What you were looking for, I assume, is [method chaining in inheritance hierarchies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069528/method-chaining-inheritance-don-t-play-well-together-java). Java does not have a clean solution afaik.

Comment: Brilliant. The link over there to http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206 is great.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have

```
Builder<SubClassOfBuilder> b = ...
SubClassOfBuilder scob = b.calories(1); // compiles fine.
```

The problem is that `b` might not be a `SubClassOfBuilder` and so you will get a ClassCastException at runtime.

Comment: But I don't have a `Builder<SubClassOfBuilder>`...? I have a `GMOFacts.Builder`

Answer (score 0):

Because NutritionFacts.Builder is a raw type. References to the generic type NutritionFacts.Builder should be parameterized if you want to avoid the compiler warning.

You should really do this:

```
public static class Builder<T extends Builder<?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because `this` is a `Builder`, and `T` is a subtype of `Builder`, doesn't mean that `this` is a `T`.

Socrates is a human. A woman is a type of human. That doesn't mean Socrates is a woman.