# How to return 'this' of child class from method of a parent class without casting?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an abstract class `Animal`:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public Animal eat() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

I have a `Cat` class wich extends `Animal`:

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat run() {
        return this;
    }
    public Cat sleep() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And with that, I want to be able to do that:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.run()
    .eat()
    .sleep();
```

But unfortunately I cannot because the `eat()` method return an instance of `Animal` and there is not `sleep()` method in `Animal` class.

An ugly solution could be to cast the `Animal` instance returned by `eat()` method in `Cat` type like this:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
((Cat) cat.run()
    .eat())
    .sleep();
```

But I don't want to do that because in my real case I am chaining a lots of methods.

**Question**: Is there a way to force method of parent class to return child instance?

Comment: Why don't you override `eat()` inside cat as `public Cat eat()`? That will return a cat.

Comment: alternatively you can make Animal an interface

Comment: Also see [What is a covariant return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type).

Comment: Overriding is not an option in my case, because I have a lots of 'mini' helper methods in my abstract class that I want to use with my child instance.

Comment: Actually as Sotirios Delimanolis says, the question is duplicated. This solution solves my problem. Sorry http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069605/5499650

Comment: @ThibaudSowa It solves your problem for one level of inheritance, but you won't be able to extend `Cat` and do the same thing for a subclass without making `Cat` generic. However, using generics to do this is ridiculous anyway. There are no examples in JDK of generics being used in this way, with good reason. The idiomatic solution is to use overriding.

Comment: @Paul Boddington thanks for this information! But in my case, I will never extend my `Cat` class, so there is no problem... But you are right to specify this for other people.

Comment: @PaulBoddington The overriding solution is also provided in the linked question.

Comment: @Paul You should comment and vote on those answers with these details.