# Referencing subclass in Java method declaration

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types

I'm trying to figure something out but googling is difficult since I'm not sure exactly what keywords are needed. Suppose I have a class like this:

```java
class MyClass {
    int i = 0;

    public MyClass increment() {
        i++;
        return this;
    }
}
```

and then I have a subclass:

```java
class MySubClass extends MyClass { }
```

and then I want do the following:

```java
MySubClass mySubClass2 = new MySubClass().increment();
```

The problem is that the object returned by `increment` is recognized as an instance of `MyClass` and not `MySubClass`, so this won't work. Is there a way to declare `increment` in `MyClass` so that it always returns something of the subclass's type?

Comment: You could override the `increment` method in your subclass to return an instance of `MySubClass`.

Comment: Right, but is there a way to have that happen automatically instead of having to override every time?

Comment: If you want to return `this` from multiple sub-classes, it will always be of their type. What you can do to save some trouble is to declare the base class and `increment()` as abstract.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method chaining + inheritance don’t play well together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069528/method-chaining-inheritance-don-t-play-well-together)

Comment: This is called a "self type" . Java does not have this feature but it's possible to achieve something similar to it with generics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use self-bounded generics:

```
class MyClass<M extends MyClass<M>> {
    int i = 0;

    public M self() {
      // unchecked cast here, because there is no guarantee that M is the self-type.
      return (M) this;
    }

    public M increment() {
        i++;
        return self();
    }
}
```

Then, extend the class like:

```
class MySubClass extends MyClass<MySubClass> { }
```

It's pretty ugly, though.

[Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/aOm7vc)